# Forbidden error 403 get in console while direct uploading to S3

Tags: javascript, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-upload

I was upload image through a server to s3 but I want to use direct uploading to S3 because of fast uploading.
I used `django-s3direct` package for direct uploading. 
I follow all step but still, I get this error.

While uploading I get error in console:

```
POST https://s3-ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/collegestudentworld-assets/img/mainpost/amar.jpg?uploads 403 (Forbidden)

initiate error: collegestudentworld-assets/img/mainpost/amar.jpg AWS Code: AccessDenied, Message:Access Deniedstatus:403
```

settings.py:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME =os.environ.get('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')

AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL = 'https://s3-ap-south-1.amazonaws.com'
#'http://' + AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME + '.s3.amazonaws.com/' #"https://collegestudentworld-assets.s3-website.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/"
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = 'ap-south-1'
AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'

STATIC_URL = 'http://' + AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME + '.s3.amazonaws.com/'
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = STATIC_URL + 'admin/'
S3DIRECT_DESTINATIONS = {
    'primary_destination': {
        'key': 'uploads/',
        'allowed': ['image/jpg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'video/mp4'],
    },
    'mainpost':{
        'key':'img/mainpost/',
        'auth': lambda u:u.is_authenticated
    },
}
```

Bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads",
                "s3:ListBucketVersions"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::collegestudentworld-assets/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:*Object*",
                "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
                "s3:AbortMultipartUpload"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::collegestudentworld-assets/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

CORS Configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>http://127.0.0.1:8000</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <ExposeHeader>x-amz-server-side-encryption</ExposeHeader>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*.collegestudentworld.com</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <ExposeHeader>ETag</ExposeHeader>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

In my browser console I get this :

```
    Starting img/mainpost/amar.jpg reason: first file

    initiate getPayloadSha256Content: e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855

initiate V4 CanonicalRequest: POST
/collegestudentworld-assets/img/mainpost/amar.jpg
uploads=
content-type:image/jpeg
host:s3-ap-south-1.amazonaws.com
x-amz-acl:public-read
x-amz-date:20200604T125344Z
content-type;host;x-amz-acl;x-amz-date
e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855
V4 stringToSign: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
6f90e1d9b91a3e557fe7f531fd735b407e29cc7f28f30655322ab5ad9ae17940
initiate signature: ebd6d06d109fff2ac35f49314a429e57019c48288073e4549d6d4c1b7ec2a10b
initiate getPayloadSha256Content: e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855

POST https://s3-ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/collegestudentworld-assets/img/mainpost/amar.jpg?uploads 403 (Forbidden)

initiate error: collegestudentworld-assets/img/mainpost/amar.jpg AWS Code: AccessDenied, Message:Access Deniedstatus:403
```

**EDIT :**

**When I make Block public access (bucket settings) is **OFF** . then everything working.**

but I have user information which is private. I don't want to make it public.
Is it okay to make it public.. any thought thanx

Comment: 403 means you aren't given access. Your code looks like you aren't supplying the `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` to anything. Have you looked at the API documentation to see the correct way to send a request?

Comment: Could you post the IAM policy for the user?

Comment: thanx for fast reply... It was working before direct uploading. 'AWS_SECRECT_ACCESS_KEY' is correct. I will look again documentation. I did from here [link](https://github.com/bradleyg/django-s3direct) @SvenWritesCode

Comment: @jellycsc IAM policy I show in Questions Bucket policy. Please chect it. Thanx

Answer (score 1):

If IAM policy for the user is set correctly then you can try these suggestions below. Instead of IAM policy, you can try adding [principal](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_principal.html) value in your bucket policy. And also make sure `Block public access (account settings)` is off and your bucket has public access.

You can try this solution:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "S3Permissions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:List*"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::collegestudentworld-assets/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

And also you can remove the `<AllowedOrigin>http://127.0.0.1:8000</AllowedOrigin>`  from `CORS` settings and can try the full path to your website or EB environment name also.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*.collegestudentworld.com</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Comment: as from here [link](https://github.com/bradleyg/django-s3direct).. they give two option one is IAM and second EC2 . Please look at [link](https://github.com/bradleyg/django-s3direct) once.  I used **django-s3direct** for direct uploading

Comment: before django-s3direct.all thing was perfect. I uploaded images through server,but it was taking lot of time to upload. then I used django-s3direct to direct upload. but I get that error.             I did all thing as per documentation of django-s3direct [link](https://github.com/bradleyg/django-s3direct)

Answer (score 0):

This is the IAM policy I use. I would make sure the IAM user who is attached to the upload policy has the correct IAM policy attached to him.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads",
                "s3:ListBucketVersions",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:HeadBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::collegestudentworld-assets/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
                "s3:*Object*",
                "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::collegestudentworld-assets/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: the problem is public access is blocked. my policy was correct. But I don't want public access because the information of users is private. Is there any way

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand what you mean by that. Can you confirm that the policy you wrote is attached to the user with the corresponding `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID ` ?

Comment: `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` is attached to user. When I make block public access is off then it's working. but when I make block public access is on then  I get forbidden error. but my  access key id and user connected. without direct uploading  It was working(with block public access is on) just taking lot of time. So I try direct uploading but I got above error.

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm being redundant. I'm trying to figure out if the user which is defined by `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` has the policy you created attached to that user. Here is a url that may help if I'm not being clear:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/walkthrough1.html#walkthrough-grant-user1-permissions

If it works publicly, you are almost at the finish line.